# GoogleCast deviceDidComeOnline(device: GCKDevice!) never getting Called #GoogleCastSDK

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

> Implemented  **GCKDeviceScannerListener** Singleton Class on ViewController, however its delegate methods are not getting called even if Logger displays message of Cast Device that is available to connect with status code 1.
>
> deviceDidComeOnline method of GCKDeviceScannerListener does not get called.

Could any one help please

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GCKDeviceScannerListener, GCKDeviceManagerDelegate, GCKMediaControlChannelDelegate {

    private var deviceScanner: GCKDeviceScanner!
    private var selectedDevice:GCKDevice!
    private var deviceManager:GCKDeviceManager!
    private var mediaInformation:GCKMediaInformation!
    private var kReceiverAppID = kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID

     override func viewDidLoad() {
    
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.startScan()
    
    }

     func startScan() {
    
        let filterCriteria = GCKFilterCriteria(forAvailableApplicationWithID: kReceiverAppID)
        self.deviceScanner = GCKDeviceScanner(filterCriteria: filterCriteria)
        if let deviceScanner = self.deviceScanner {
            deviceScanner.addListener(self)
            deviceScanner.startScan()
            print("scanning started")
            deviceScanner.passiveScan = true
        }
    }


    // MARK: GCKDeviceScannerListener

    func deviceDidComeOnline(device: GCKDevice!) {
        print("deviceDidComeOnline()")
        print("Device found: \(device.friendlyName)");
        self.updateButtonStates()

    }

    func deviceDidGoOffline(device: GCKDevice!) {
        print("deviceDidGoOffline()")
        print("Device went away: \(device.friendlyName)");
        self.updateButtonStates()

    }

    func deviceDidChange(device: GCKDevice!) {
        print("deviceDidChange()");
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't dealt with Swift, but it looks like the listener is only added inside an `if` condition - this might be the cause of your issue. Try to remove it from there and hopefully it will work, your snippet is similar to the sample from the iOS Cast documentation.

Comment: Your code looks fine. I've implemented something very similar and mine works. Dumb question but, did you make sure you are on the same network as the chromecast device?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse I am on the same network buddy :P

Answer (score 0):

Enter the ID that you receive after registering your App at [Google Cast Registration](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration)
I have just used your code and it worked Perfect.
Don't use the default ID. It wouldn't work i.e

> kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID

```
let filterCriteria = GCKFilterCriteria(forAvailableApplicationWithID: kReceiverAppID)
```

Instead of it, Enter the ID to pass in the filter criteria and implement it like this.

```
let chromecastID = "ABC123" // Enter the correct ID here 
let filterCriteria = GCKFilterCriteria(forAvailableApplicationWithID: chromecastID)
```